# how to check and change location method in flutter?

Tags: android, flutter

[how to check and change location method in flutter?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Eu8JA.jpg)

i want current location of user iam using

final Geolocator geolocator = Geolocator()..forceAndroidLocationManager = true;

```
Position position = await geolocator
    .getCurrentPosition(desiredAccuracy: LocationAccuracy.high,);
double lat2=position.latitude;
double lon2=position.longitude;


await Firestore.instance.collection('tabdata').document('deliverystatus').get().then((DocumentSnapshot document) {
  lat1= document.data['latitude'];
  lon1= document.data['longitude'];
});
```

but if location method is set to device only it dose not work at all is there any way to set android location method to high accuracy by default in flutter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way of doing it programmatically. What you can do is, launch Location Settings screen with [`android_intent`](https://pub.dev/packages/android_intent) plugin, and tell user to switch accuracy.

```
var url = 'android.settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS';
if (await canLaunch(url)) {
  await launch(url);
}
```

And beginning with Android 29, there is no such option like `High Accuracy`.